# How can i make my python program run faster? I get "killed 9" message with following code

Tags: python

I'm trying to demonstrate bijection between natural and rational numbers, from N to Q. When i run the code, it runs some time after which the process get terminated with "killed 9" message.

"n" represent natural number, "o" numerator and "m" denominator

Heres my code:

```
import numpy as np
 
n,m,o = 1766445895,1,1
N,M,O=[],[],[]
O.append(o)
M.append(m)
N.append(n)
go_on = True
while go_on:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n=(n-2)//2
        N.append(n)
        
    elif n % 2 == 1:
        n=(n-1)//2
        N.append(n)
    elif n<=0:
        go_on = False

for i in range(len(N)):
    if N[i] % 2 == 0:
       o=m+o
       O.append(o)
       M.append(m)
    if N[i] % 2 == 1:
       m=o+m
       O.append(o)
       M.append(m)

for i in range(len(N)):

    if i < 10:
        print('{:d}:  n = {:10d}, q = {:6d}/{:6d}'.format(i, N[i],O[i],M[i]))
    else:
        print('{:d}: n = {:10d}, q = {:6d}/{:6d}'.format(i, N[i],O[i],M[i]))
```

Comment: `go_on` is never set to `False` as one of the previous conditions  in the `if/elif` will always be `True` - `n % 2` will always be either `1` or `0`. Move `if n <= 0:` to be the first condition

Comment: That sounds more like some other process is sending SIGKILL to your process, which it can neither ignore nor react to: the OS "delivers" the signal by simply terminating the process instead.

Comment: As @chepner has said, signal 9 (SIGKILL) cannot be caught. It's sounds like some kind of monitor process (or maybe Python itself) is alerting that it is going to send SIGKILL. Also, why not replace *while go_on* with *while n > 0* Have you also considered that *N* can only ever contain even numbers?

Comment: Thanks for help, it works now, the problem was with go_on structure. Changed it to while n > 0 as advised.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified as:

```
N, M, O = [1766445895], [1], [1]
n, m, o = N[0], M[0], O[0]

while n > 0:
    n = (n-2)//2 if n % 2 == 0 else (n-1)//2
    N.append(n)
    if n % 2 == 0:
        o += m
    else:
        m += o
    O.append(o)
    M.append(m)

for i, (_n, _o, _m) in enumerate(zip(N, O, M)):
    print(f'{i}:  n = {_n:10d}, q = {_o:6d}/{_m:6d}')
```